# Is it possible to detect which file sent a XMLHttpRequest using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Imagine I'm running a JavasScript application which has dozens of different .Js files in the domains root

```
Controller.JS
Picker.JS
**DataSync.JS -** And this file performs GET request to PHP file 
Players.JS
```

Now the devtools shows request beeing made from mydomain.com?myrequest
How can I validate using PHP, if the request came from DataSync.JS file?

Comment: You can't. PHP (and your webserver in general) doesn't even know for sure if it was an XHR request, or if the request even came from a browser at all (as opposed to any other program which can make HTTP requests). A HTTP request is just a bunch of text, at the end of the day. The whole point of it is to transparently decouple the client from the server in the architecture. So...why would your PHP code need to know that information? It should not be concerned with the small details of the client-side application. What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm building a simple game and looking for a ways to validate requests, if it has been done in the app itself, and the app's code haven't been changed/injected/etc, since a http request can be made from literally anywhere

Comment: Since you can't trust the client not to forge anything and pretend to be the application, then realistically you can't do it in quite the way you're imagining. I think what you're actually looking for here is probably authentication. Or it might just be that CSRF tokens are adequate - depends on the level and type of protection you're interested in.

Comment: Using PHP's `$_SESSION` parameter is the best way to authenticate/validate

Comment: @ControlAltDel depends on the exact scenario, I'd say. A non browser client could also establish a Session, potentially.  For the server to differentiate, it needs a bit more than just that.

Comment: You could send some kind of auth token with every request - a token that changes on each request. Only the server should be able to retrieve and generate the token and lookup what the current token is. This way you can only accept requests with the correct token and be sure its not the client or anyone else sending the request.

Comment: ^^^ ...and that's basically what CSRF tokens are.

Comment: @ADyson "A non browser client" - true. But if they are connecting via http(s), session should still be viable. Or are you talking about connecting via non-http?

Comment: Ensuring that the application has not been tampered with is what anti-cheat game engines like Denuvo do, and they need to do nasty things to the entire client computer to have a small chance of not being defeated for the first weeks after release. You surely don't need that level of protection, so you may want to provide more detail of your ultimate goal.

Comment: Still, requests would be made from client-side in my case as I get variables directly from that file, unless I re-create the whole application, I could, however, instead of HTTP request, put variables into URL and read using PHP, but again, how would I validate that, the file did entered the variables and not the user typed, any other ways to safely pass Javascript variables to PHP and to know that it had been send from the file, not console, not extension etc

Comment: @ControlAltDel I wasn't suggesting non-HTTPS, no. Are you thinking of the scenario where someone steals an insecure Session ID or cookie? Of course that can be mitigated by HTTPS and prevention of XSS, etc. But that wasn't my point. I'm saying that if you simply rely on a Session ID to show that the client is part of an application, that isn't sufficient because any client can establish a session and pass the cookie back and forth. There has to be something extra which establishes that the client is valid - e.g. some auth token is passed which the server can verify....

Comment: ... @ControlAltDel a Session can be part of that solution, but by itself it does not provide any particular security.

Comment: @MLStudios exactly what problem would it cause if the request comes from an application which isn't your own game application? a) you can authenticate requests so they only come from valid _users_, and b) your server can validate requests so they only are accepted if they contain data which makes logical sense. What are you trying to solve here - is it to prevent some sort of cheating?

Comment: @ADyson, Yes, to prevent cheating, the problem is that I'm using a game engine (PlayCanvas) and it's fully client side, all I have is the main .js file that gets variables and sends request to server with those variables, but variables can be easily replaced in console or any other method, I have to rely on those since some in-game calculations etc cannot be made in server side, my plan was to: compare if users client md5sum is same as orginal, detect if request was made from the right file (not from devtools or any other location) but seems like I will have to edit the whole app

Comment: As I cannot 'get' those variables from server side, calculations lik model mesh instances, model size in game world, player positions etc cannot be calculated in server

Comment: `since some in-game calculations etc cannot be made in server side`....why not? Or could the server not at least validate that they make sense? Obviously I don't know what the game is. TBH I'm not a game dev and I don't know how web or mobile game makers guard against cheating, but I'd bet you can do some research about it online rather than inventing your own solutions. For web apps in general, you simply never trust anything which comes from the client, and always re-validate it at the server side.

Comment: @ADyson game concept is fairly simple: users who has permissions, builds the world with external uploaded models (glb, gltf) I have to check model sizes in the game, calculate triangles and other data in game, what matthers the most is players position, and custom model position in world that can only be acquired from client side, I do have some logic to unload abnormal models that do not pass defined criteria the last step is those variables, can't think of a solution yet, what's hardest to spoof? Cookie or..?

Comment: Cookies are easy to spoof tbh. If your app compiles and can't easily be decompiled, you could maybe put some unique GUID value or something into the build which is secret, and which the app must send with each request. But of course if that value somehow becomes known, a user could then use it to craft a malicious request.

Comment: `what matters the most is players position, and custom model position in world`...again I'm not in full possession of all the facts, but could the server not mirror the game state and validate that when it's submitted? The only games I have ever implemented myself are fairly simple turn-based ones, so it's pretty trivial to keep the game state on the server and therefore make sure that any move submitted by the user is legal. Not sure how that would work with something more real-time - again I'd guess you can research this online and some subject experts might have more guidance for you.